# Azure Pipeline load variable template based on environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to use the same yaml file to deploy to dev, int and prod.  I do want to have three folders in the DevOps UI referring to the same yaml file:

[image]

I know I can do it using `parameters` and `predefined variables`, e.g.:

```
- name: env
  displayName: Environment
  type: string
  default: int
  values:
  - int
  - dev
  - prod

variables:
- template: ./variables/${{ parameters.env }}_variables.yml
```

will load the `dev_variables.yaml` or the according selected one.  But like this someone could select the wrong environment in the wrong UI folder, resulting in a "wrong" deployment history.

I can use different steps with a condition but I cannot use `Build.DefinitionName` since it contains the pipeline name but not the folder (dev, int ,prod).  Also runtime variables defined per pipeline in the UI would be fine for me but cannot be used.  Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

**Edit:** I do not want to deploy all env at once but one by one.  No trigger by a specific branch or alike.  I want to trigger them manually.

Comment: This is what stages are for. Use stages. You don't need to pass in a parameter for environment.

Comment: Using stages I would always deploy all stages with one pipeline run. Or how can I set from the outside to just deploy stage 1 (e.g. dev) in this run?  Can you maybe post an example or link.  Thank you.  I need a condition to be set.  As mentioned I did not succeed.

Comment: You can control what stages run by selecting them in the UI prior to queuing the pipeline. You can also use `deployment` jobs tied to environments and put required approvals between stages.

Comment: Ok understood, need to change my mindset and will use proper environments and the according history for monitoring.  Thank you for your input.